# Magento ver. 1.9.3.2 - Order Emails Are Not Sending

Tags: magento-1.9

I noticed my email queue is stuck.

There are 2 tables in the database core_email_queue and core_email_recipients.

core_email_queue contains all the emails to be sent.
core_email_recipients contains who to send those emails to.

I am wondering how i can resolve this ?  Also just 3 days before I was changing my host, and all my customers received order confirmation.

Please suggest, should i manually clear all dates from "core_email_queue" ?

Also can i also delete all cleared all data from core_email_recipients?

I'd be grateful if you can share your views or solution for my issue.

Thank you

Comment: Did you configure cron job in sever ?

Comment: No cron job is very much default.

Answer (score 3):

Since **Magento 1.9.1** the emails are not being sent directly during checkout but instead are being **queued**. The queue is being processed via your **Magento cronjob**, please ensure this has been [set up](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html#install-cron) and is running correctly.

Moreover The extension [AOE_Scheduler](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html) can help you in confirming that your Magento cronjob has been configured correctly and is running.

Answer (score 1):

there are many reasons for this issue , if I'd debug it I'd use [n98-magerun](http://magerun.net/installation/) and I'd try to run the cron : `core_email_queue_send_all` with the following command :

> php n98-magerun.phar sys:cron:run core_email_queue_send_all

this will run the cron manually , I think it output error if you have any errors thrown

you might also try to see error log filed in `var/log/system.log` & `var/log/exception.log`

Comment: Appreciated for your response.

I really wants to get our from corn related things, by using below extension

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html

Do you think, if i just cleared up my two tables in database core_email_recipients and core_email_queue.  then it won't effect anything on other operations ??? 

Thank you

Comment: it will delete all the emails your customers are waiting

Answer (score 0):

go to app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php

line 407 put

```
if (!($this->hasQueue()) && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue)
```

mail work properly.